# Delete empty rows from spreadsheet via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function removeEmptyRows(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows(); 
  var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  sh.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
}
```

When activating the script it returns an error saying:

> These lines are out of range (Line 5)

My Spreadsheet:
[image]

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I think that when `maxRows-lastRow` is 0 or less than 0, such error occurs. So please confirm whether there are the values to the bottom row of the sheet. If there are not values to the bottom row of the sheet, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? I would like to confirm it.

As a modification point for avoiding the error, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sh.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
```

#### To:

```
if (maxRows-lastRow > 0) {
  sh.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
}
```

#### Other pattern:

Or, how about removing the empty rows using the data region from the 1st row as follows?

```
function removeEmptyRows(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRowOfDataRegion = sh.getRange("1:1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow();
  var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows(); 
  if (maxRows-lastRowOfDataRegion > 0) {
    sh.deleteRows(lastRowOfDataRegion+1, maxRows-lastRowOfDataRegion);
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getDataRegion(dimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getDataRegion(Dimension))

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: The second option worked in my case, the first option did not warn of errors in the script but did not delete the rows. So I will use the second option, thank you very much.

Comment: I have more than one spreadsheet page and tried to define the page, the script does not return in error but also does not delete the lines. Could you show me what should look like? I tried like this:  
```var lastRowOfDataRegion = sh.getRange("Registros!A1:AD")```

Comment: @Brondby IF If you want to run the script for the sheets except for the active sheet, for example, how about modifying `var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` to `var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("### sheet name ###")`? But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So if this didn't resolve your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeEmptyRows(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(sh.getLastRow()<sh.getMaxRows()) {
    sh.deleteRows(sh.getLastRow()+1, sh.getMaxRows()-sh.getLastRow());
  }
}
```